# Replace tag with another in Python Django

Tags: python, replace, beautifulsoup

I have working with **Python** and I have some questions:

1. I am using **BeautifulSoup** I want to replace an HTML tag with another one.

Here is code example:

```
html = BeautifulSoup(p)
            x = html.find('a', attrs={'href':'/slideshow'})

            while x:
                print 'x unchanged - ', x
                x=x.replaceWith('<a href="/slideshow_v2">')
                print 'x changed - ', x
```

Thanks for help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a solution to your problem:

```
html = BeautifulSoup(p)
anchors = html.findAll('a', href='/slideshow')

for anchor in anchors:
    anchor['href'] = '/slideshow_v2'

print html.findAll('a', href='/slideshow_v2')
```

Take into acount please that this is not a Django related question.

Good luck!